# Change UILabel font to bold when highlighted

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uilabel

I have a UITableView with static cells. Each cell has some custom labels. If the cell is selected, the labels in it are automatically set to highlighted. I want to change their text to bold when this happens. There are about 50 labels so I don't want to have 50 outlets. Any ideas how I can accomplish this?

Comment: You should probably subclass the cell to change the label font when it's selected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I figured it out. If I use didSelectRowAtIndexPath, I would have to create over 50 outlets or switch to dynamic content. Instead, I am overriding the highlighted property of UILabel in a subclass and making the changes there.

```
class HighlightLabel: UILabel {

    override var highlighted: Bool {
        didSet {
            if highlighted {
                self.font = UIFont.boldSystemFontOfSize(self.font.pointSize)
            } else {
                self.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(self.font.pointSize)
            }
        }   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should the delegate method provided:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)

        for view in cell.contentView.subviews{
            if view.isKindOfClass(UILabel) {
                 //Magic

            }
        }
}
```

And to revert back to normal:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)

        for view in cell.contentView.subviews{
            if view.isKindOfClass(UILabel) {
                 //Un-Magic
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Nope. This requires creating outlets.